# Need to replace excel formulas in SQL with vlook & Matchh

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement wherein i have to move the excel work to sql.
hence excel is calculating the based on the vlookup & Match function formulas

= =VLOOKUP(AM2,'End User'!C:O,MATCH('APJ Source File'!AT2,'End User'!$C$1:$N$1,0),0).

can you please help me incorporate this in SQL.

Comment: We can't give you an exact answer without knowing what your SQL table structure is.  Please include that, possibly along with some sample data.

Comment: i will explain with as per the table --> Vlookup column (ID) from current table (table1), to the end_user table (A:O) (table2). and then need to Match colum LOb from table1 to end user table (table2) from 1st row, & derive the exact match.

Comment: i will explain with as per the table --> Vlookup column (ID) from current table (table1), to the end_user table (A:O) (table2). and then need to Match colum LOb from table1 to end user table (table2) from 1st row, & derive the exact match. – Suresh H 1 hour ago     Delete